# Is i-​- special in while loop?

Tags: java

I was working on a while loop which has i-- decrease but I was expecting 10 to use twice. In my opinion, we use 10 at the beginning and then while loop starts. We write 10 because of System.out.println(i); and then we see i--; .. So I think we have 10 again to use and then we decrease it to the 9. Can you explain why the output returns as below?

```
int i=10;

 while(i>1){

  System.out.println(i);

  i--;

 }
```

Expected output is
10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2

but it gives 
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2

Comment: You only print `i` once before it changes from `10` to `9`.  So I'm not sure why you would expect it to be printed twice.

Comment: I think the debugger would be your best friend for this.

Comment: The loop enters, `i` is `10`. It prints `i`, so `10`. Next, it decreases `i` by `1`, so `9`. Next loop iteration, printing `i`, so `9`. Not sure why you expected `10` to come twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Misconception on your end: these pre/post fix operations only affect the "current" expression. They have **no** notion of some enclosing loop context for example. You assume that the `--i` somehow magically affects the while condition. It doesn't. See [here](http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-increment-decrement-operators.php) for some further reading.

Your code goes:

1. i = 10
2. is i > 10 ... sure: enter the loop
3. print i
4. i = i -1
5. goto 2

In other words: if you want to see differences in the printed output, change your code to do:

```
System.out.println(--i);
System.out.println(i--);
```

for example.

In your code, you have that operation **on its own line**. Therefore, that line could be written as `i--`, `--i`, or `i = i -1` or `i -= 1`. Doesn't matter. The expression decrements i, and stores the new value. Again: to see different outcome, you need to **use** the result of that operation directly!

Answer (score 0):

What you said is not true, when you enter into the while loop it is the first iteration already, so the first printed value is 10. Then you decrease the value so the second is going to be 9.

Comment: But why? First we see the print commend and then we see the decreasing i-- which says "First take as 10, then decrease to 9". Does this order not matter?

Comment: @DavyJones Indeed this order doesn't matter. It would if you added steps between first and then, which you could. But you don't, so, it doesn't matter that there is a first and a then. Both happen, and you're left with the result of it.

Comment: @DavyJones as they said :) You print (so you see 10), then you decrease (value decreased to 9), then you print again on the second iteration (you see 9), then you decrease... and so on...

Comment: Edited. I had wrote it wrong. I'm sorry. Would you check it again please?

Comment: @DavyJones it is exactly the same, the only difference, as GhostCat said, would be if you would use `--i` or `i--` inside the `System.out.println`